# Kendo UI Inline Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having an issue with validation on certain fields.  I want to only validate on a couple of fields, and the other fields should not validate.  In my Email field, I am firing a function to check proper formatting, but the other fields are simply set to validate.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 model: {
            id: "UserID",
            fields: {
                UserID: { editable: false },
                CompanyID: { editable: false },
                FirstName: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "Name is required"} } },
                LastName: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "Name is required" } } },
                Email: {
                    type: "string",
                    validation: {
                        required: { message: "Email is required." },
                        validateEmailFormat: function(input) {
                            if (input.attr("data-bind") == "value:Email") {
                                input.attr("data-validateEmailFormat-msg", "Email format invalid.");
                                return checkEmail(input.val());
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                },
                PhoneNumber: { type: "string" },
                Extension: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
```

With this code, all fields are being validated when trying to save/update.  I don't want Extension or PhoneNumber to validate.

Comment: What kind of validation apply on the PhoneNumber and Extension?Please check you `ViewModel`. is there any annotation for the PhoneNumber and Extension?

Answer (score 0):

In your update/Save action, You can remove your fields from the `ModelState` which don't want to valid,  like :

```
ModelState.Remove("PhoneNumber");
ModelState.Remove("Extension");
```